# Play .wav files with Naudio lib

Tags: c#, .net, audio, naudio

I try open and play `.wav` files with NAudio lib.

```
private OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = null;
private NAudio.Wave.IWavePlayer waveOutDevice;
private NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream reductionStream = null;

private NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream CreateStream(OpenFileDialog fileDialog)
{

    if (fileDialog.FileName.EndsWith(".mp3"))
    {
        NAudio.Wave.WaveStream pcm = NAudio.Wave.WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(fileDialog.FileName));
        reductionStream = new NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream(pcm);
    }
    else if (fileDialog.FileName.EndsWith(".wav"))
    {
        NAudio.Wave.WaveStream pcm = new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(openFileDialog.FileName));
        reductionStream = new NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream(pcm);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported");
    }

    return reductionStream;
}
```

and in play button:

```
waveOutDevice = new NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut();
reductionStream = CreateStream(openFileDialog);
waveOutDevice.Init(reductionStream);
```

I'm using NAudio 1.5 version. For mp3 files, that play's good. When I select `.wav`, playing are slowly, and creaking. Maybe something wrong with WaveStream `pcm = WaveChannel32`?

Comment: A snail is slow, a door creaks.  These are not terms that describe audio playback problems well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use BlockAlignReductionStream, WaveChannel32 or CreatePcmStream. Just use the Mp3FileReader or WaveFileReader and pass that in to your IWavePlayer,